# discord.js Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') after sending the message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
Client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online')
});

Client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id = '915302302682873909') {
        const logChannel = Client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "915302371519770664");
        //send author
        logChannel.send(`${message.author}` + ": ")
            .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`));
        //send message content
        logChannel.send(message.content)
            .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`));
    }
})
```

If I start up my bot and send a message to see if it works, it sends the `` `${message.author}` + ": " `` as it should but then immediately crashes saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')`
What's also really weird is that sometime (I couldn't figure out when) it sends both `` `${message.author}` + ": " `` and `message.content` before crashing.

Comment: That means the channel could not be found. Instead of finding the channel in cache try fetching the channel. `const logChannel = Client.channels.fetch('915302371519770664');`. Or if you couldnt find the channel return the function. `if(!logChannel) return;`

Comment: If I do this it says that logChannel.send isn't a function

Comment: As you're fetching a new channel make sure to resolve its promise with either an `await` in an asynchronous function or save the channel in a `.then` callback function

Comment: Also why are you using template literals for everything but the first send method?

Comment: I was looking up other solutions before and tried some stuff and didn't remove it afterwards

Comment: Now it is like a one time use, the first message after starting the bot will get perfectliy copied to the logChannel but if I try to send a second message the bot will crash stating: 
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
channel_id: Value "false" is not snowflake

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `logChannel` is undefined.

If your id is correct, you could define it like this:

````js
const logChannel = Client.channels.cache.get('915302371519770664') || Client.channels.fetch('915302371519770664');```
````